# Consume Jersey WebService I/O

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, swagger

i need to create a project which read/consume a jersey impl service and get i/o methods specs, like this example:

on the request with jersey api through this uri

https://portal.com/security/rest/users?fullname=name%20surname

uri response:

[{"username":"username","fullname":"name surname"}]

i have to know which in the other side is like that:

```
  @GET
  @Path("/users")
  @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  public User getUsers(@QueryParam("fullname") fullname) {
    return null;
  }
```

And have to write a XML **or** JSON approximately:

```
<method name="getUsers">
    <request type="param">
     <parameters type="QueryParam" name="fullname"/>
    </request>
    <response type="MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON" object="User">
    <array type="Object">
      <object>
        <username>username</username>
        <fullname>name surname</fullname>
      </object>
    </array>
    </response>
</method>
```

PS: the response of my api may be in json also

What method u have for me? Read WADL ? Swagger or other api can do that for me? (Describe a rest webservice in runtime getting a description of all methods)

Comment: See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question whether you have control on the server-side as well or not.

If you do, you can integrate [swagger-core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/) in it to expose a Swagger specification from your application at runtime. You can then use [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen) to create a client using several frameworks and languages from that spec. The resulting clients have zero dependency (or awareness) of Swagger.

Comment: Right, but does the rest service you're trying to consume provide a Swagger documentation for its service?

Comment: my app isn't a rest service, i consume (or impl (on runtime, is it possible?)) rest service. So, the client which have the jersey rest service need to implement the tool in your services?

Comment: No, the service does not implement swagger, they use Jersey

Comment: Swagger is a documentation spec. If they don't provide a Swagger doc, you'd need to create one manually in order to utilize it. Same goes for WADL or anything else for that matter.

Comment: create a swagger doc at run time? is it possible?

Comment: It's possible if the server integrates a Swagger library as part of the application.

Comment: then anyway my client need to integrate swagger, and with swagger i can consume with swagger-core or swagger-codegen

Comment: For java clients, you only need swagger-codegen. swagger-core is for producing documentation.

Comment: hmmm, looks like swagger-codegen is for java 7 =/ oh

Comment: It generates clients based on templates. You can change the template to suit your needs.

Comment: to end this topic, i can't enter with a URI homepage of a rest service and get a describe of them without this rest service implement swagger-codegen, right ?

Comment: I'm not sure. There may be projects that offer dynamic binding of Swagger endpoints, but I don't know if/how they work.

Comment: Sure... The problem is: my project response need to be the i/o of a rest service. How i do, that is the problem, today we use wadl parser for our clients.

Comment: Your last comment is a bit unclear, but using the comment system here is not a good way to go over it. If you want to get direct assistance, use either our google group or IRC channel. Info at the bottom of http://swagger.io.